# Using `Component` without decorator

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

To avoid AOT static compilation error on `ng build`, I am trying to avoid decorators.
I am trying to acheive it like this:

```
class BaseComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.initialiizeData();
    }
}

export const AppComponent = Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    template: `
        <div class="button">
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./button.less'],
})(Basecomponent);
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent 1: (?, ?).
```

Comment: import statement?

Comment: Where is the constructor with two parameters?

Comment: This is because you're exporting a variable reference, a.k.a. a class  instance. NgModules need classes to instatiate them on their own. You won't be able to remove the decorator to create components, sorry. But in the meantime, those decorators have been made to work with AOT builds, so you shouldn't have any issues with it as long as you use them correctly.